# DevDemon Credits decode_date deprecated

Tags: devdemon

DevDemon Credits v2.5.3a includes a deprecated method decode_date which was removed in #eecms v1.9.2.

Comment: Hey Leevi - bug reports should go straight to devs, not here.

Answer (score 1):

In ajax.credits.php line 193:

```
$this->EE->localize->decode_date('%d-%M-%Y %g:%i %A', $row->date))
```

should be replaced with:

```
$this->EE->localize->format_date('%d-%M-%Y %g:%i %A', $row->date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Credits 2.5.4 fixes this issue.